# Converting project to Xamarin Unified api: "Failed to load output manifest for actool for the file..."

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm converting a project to the new unified api from Xamarin. I've converted all my methods and project settings. But when I run the project in debug I'm getting the following error message when building my project:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: error : Failed to load output manifest for actool for the file obj/iPhone/Debug FT/actool/asset-manifest.plist: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index
```

Currently working with Xamarin Studio version 5.7 (build 660) and Xamarin.iOS version 8.6.0.41.

Did someone already fixed this problem? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

In iOS8 Apple changed something that requires the Asset Catalog to be used for images.
So I created an asset catalog for my Launch images and icon images and my project was building without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't faced this problem but I saw some people talking about this and there are 2 possible solution (known to me),

First is to clean the project and re run.

another is manually installing latest [Xamarin installer](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads)

Comment: I've already tried to reinstall Xamarin studio but that didn't work.